# php 5.6.1 build configuration error.

Tags: php, php-internals

I am installing php 5.6.1 on centos 7 from build. I did the standard pull, configure but when I make build I get these configuration errors, even though the process continues and terminates with success. What does this error mean and how can I fix it. [image]

Comment: Try disabling any zend modules, and see if it compiles.

Comment: @MikePurcell How do I disable the zend modules? I use to install php similar way some months back, and it worked then w/o any problems.

Comment: Been awhile since I have compiled manually, as I use the Remi repo (http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) to install PHP, I checked my old school compilation notes and didn't see any specific zend references. Be sure to issue `make clean` before starting the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP - like most languages, uses a lexer generator and a parser generator for its grammar.

The tools PHP uses are the ubiquitous Bison and lesser used re2c - these are binaries that take specially formatted source files and output C code no one would ever really want to write by hand.  But these generated C files are part of the distribution source of php, so you CAN compile php without the tools, you just get warnings from the build system.

You only really need bison and re2c if you're changing the lexer or parser definition files so the C code needs to be regenerated.

You would need to install the centos packages for bison and re2c to make the first few warnings go away

yum groupinstall "Development Tools" should get what you need, otherwise you'll need to search yum for the bison and re2c packages

the other warnings (const mismatch and others) are simply because PHP source code is noisy (some sloppy code) at higher gcc warning levels